# Which theme PHP file should be edited in order to change Posts appearance

Tags: theme-development

Thank you in advance,

I know that if you want to edit the appearence of the search page there is search.php file that you can mess with.

I am using TOTAL theme in wordpress, I have decided to customize the themes POSTS page appearance completely, I did inspect element to look and tried matching the code with themes files but I could not find the codes. Where are the codes written. Which file should I look into.

Answer (score 0):

The home.php contains the blog page and single.php contains the code to display a single item. I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

[QueryMonitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin (it is *free*) to the rescue! Among other debugging staff, QueryMonitor has a *"Template"* sub-menu when in front-end, which also displays the current template file in use.
[image: query-monitor_submenu]

Moreover, when you click the *"Template"* sub-menu, you get a lot more useful details:
[image: query-monitor_template-details]

1) The template file currently in use.

2) What template-parts that are being called from inside the used template (for more details, you can check the [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) function).

3) The template hierarchy starting from the most specific and going to the most generic. e.g: Now we are using the `single.php` template. But if we create the `single-post-what-template-should-i-change.php` (*what-template-should-i-change* is the slug of the post I was currently watching) template file, then we can create a unique tempalte ONLY for that specific post.

Hope, that helps.

P.S: I'm not affiliated to the plugin whatsoever, just using it and it really helps!